# vala: quotient of two integers is always an integer. Why?

Tags: vala

Newbie question:

```
void main () {
    int A = 1;
    int B = 2;
    double C = A / B;
    stdout.printf("C value is: %g\n", C);
}
```

This prints: "C value is: 0"

```
void main () {
    int A = 1;
    double B = 2;
    double C = A / B;
    stdout.printf("C value is: %g\n", C);
}
```

This prints: "C value is: 0.5"

I don't understand the reason why the result is not 0.5 in both cases.

Answer (score 6):

The division operation is performed on two integers, so the result is an integer.  The fact that you assign it to a double afterwards doesn't change that.

What you're doing in your question, with the implicit conversions made explicit, is

```
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
double C = (double) (A / B);
```

However, if you want to perform the division operation using doubles you have to explicitly cast at least one of the operands to double:

```
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
double C = ((double) A) / B;
```

For the rules concerning arithmetic operations, see the [arithmetic expressions section of the Vala Manaual](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Manual/Expressions#Arithmetic_operations).  The relevant bit:

> If both operands are of integer types, then the result will be the quotient only of the calculation (equivalent to the precise answer rounded down to an integer value.) If either operand is of a floating point type, then the result will be as precise as possible within the boundaries of the result type (which is worked out from the basic arithmetic type rules.)

Comment: C has the "usual arithmetic conversions" that are a set of rules when different numeric types are used in an expression. This standard achieves consistency across compilers, but isn't necessarily "obvious" because it involves the implicit casting of numeric types. Inexperienced programmers or programmers with experience in different languages can be caught out by the rules. This can lead to an unexpected loss of precision in the result. See the MISRA C guidelines for attempts to address this. Vala compiles to C code and, as I understand it, follows the same type conversion rules.

Comment: The "obvious" thing was (interestingly, I edited it out before you posted your comment) in reference to an example I decided to delete before I posted where I asked what the type C in `var C = A / B;` would be. Vala compiles to C, but that's not why it is the same in this case; the language specification explicitly defines the same behavior.

Comment: Yes, I should have removed the double quotes around obvious once I spotted you had changed the wording :) The section of the Vala manual for this is very succinct. It helps make it clear the implicit casting rules for what type the result will be when number types are of different width, e.g. int32 and int64, or different number formats, e.g. int and double.